# In App Purchasing

Tags: ios, app-store

I am building an app that downloads an XML file and ultimately presents stats for financial quarters.

If I wish to add a button that prompts the user to allow another quarters worth of data, can I simply add a boolean value to my app, send them to the store, toggle the flag and allow the download of further XML files from my website?

Read many articles on the web, but my head is spinning!
Ideally I would prefer apple to handle all the backend restoration of data on the device once it is purchased :)

Any useful links or advice would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes. It depends how secure you want the process to be.

In your suggested way, the paid-for content (your XML files) still remain accessible to download across the public internet. You could authenticate the download, but that will require infrastructure on your end, rather than Apple's.

Basically, once a user goes off and makes an in-app purchase your app is sent back a) whether the transaction was successful, and b) if so, an iTunes receipt.

The receipt is critical, since it allows you to verify someone really has paid for the item they're trying to get. Most developers implement receipt validation on their own servers (although you can, in theory, do it on device as well).

You may decide if your app has a sufficiently small market that this isn't required. For apps where it could be quite likely people would want to pirate data, perhaps you want to consider some receipt verification.

It is possible to use a third-party service to simplify the process, if it's something you find a little too complex to integrate yourself. I've never used any myself, but one I've heard reasonable things about is Urban Airship's IAP service: http://urbanairship.com/

Comment: Ah cool ok, So Its reasonable for me to be able allow the download once I have managed the receipt validation, awesome.